# Node.js how to ungzip GET response made through TCP socket

Tags: node.js, tcp, get, gzip

When i send a GET request to Hearthstone website, and once i've concatenated all the sent frames, i still get a compressed string

My request:

```
GET /hearthstone/en/ HTTP/1.1
Host: eu.battle.net
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://www.google.fr/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Cookie: eu-cookie-compliance-agreed=1; _ga=GA1.3.780909635.1489783325; _gat_bnetgtm=1
```

My logs:

```
[Socket] > Connected !
Connected to 185.60.115.40
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
--- Header ---
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 18 Mar 2017 10:56:12 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Retry-After: 600
Content-Language: en-GB
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=4000
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8

4331
▼      ♥��{�∟W�'��
�1�4_`�4→������s㑑�*V��H��(�2����s�=��8w��▼v���▲�3���d���[�k��N�rw�_U��������↔��xd�q<zIe♠T�Ƅe�݁��1▼졲b��|#▼w���l8U���ɠ�L�z�(�?�6��b♠e���y�bw�N�XUy>��↑↑"�*�U���MJ50F♦�Z�_�_�6���↓�R>Q�j☼��*9V;b�ȧj�nZ��j��~�XQ��U�)��$IE�&�'l��'i�n��R[�&iv`¶j☻�����/TRcT☻��E+&�♥6e��∟f�→i\�◄�☻��♣=������+]�Ŗ�|)�§)���r<e�v⸉♀}���Ȳm�EI�Ca{�u_�♫z,���↑���:,[��X�T6J�����§�����♂"?◄▲w�g♣Q �(♠Fu4S
l�-��l�
������~K�>*�Leu�T�(�↓�ָ-p ���q��'j(����▲$M�9����*tz►d`����T↔��[=�?Le��+§ȯL��c�YZ���R�
♀�zY�DYBL��♦��  ‼��n�y������gh�x²r�f����ady1e�&�P������Y�ͭ�►7�y1��}
v�����,�◄‼-��
,�X�$n∟Z>�=�$��1���k���'*rc�☼bK��§$�r�ͅ�����+�X�§♂/f�↔s♂§mΤ�#ԳC�ZV↑�    g☺�l7�<♠f��$t���*����H►��'�Jҗ�׍�z�����hU*i↕��
��w�΃f�↕�FA�8,f�=�4QQ�]�♫-�     �#8♥��V■♂� �ȋ�������g♥♣▼�!�B˶D↕A↑E<H,♂� dQ1�N ��sm'♫�L☻m()� f��<I֯����\♠Y�H�TH�8�\�Cԡ7cGz�↔p x Ӄ,��P��k�>wb�8�#� i�‼~∟+t�▼♦�+"W��‼:��@�Z�Q� �0r�↔8"�↔?N<��aU�Q��������8�↓w��B��VB�Z♫�☺↨◄�9���l��§��P▼H1?☻Nv¶J.l
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket - Data] > Received data !
[Socket] > End message received !
--- HTML ---
<Buffer 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e 31 20 32 30 30 20 4f 4b 0d 0a 44 61 74 65 3a 20 53 61 74 2c 20 31 38 20 4d 61 72 20 32 30 31 37 20 31 30 3a 35 36 3a 31 32 20 47 ... >
```

My code:

```
send ()
{
    let chuncks = []


    this.client.socket.once('data', data =>
    {
        /* Header */
        chuncks.push(data)
        console.log('--- Header ---')
        console.log(data.toString())

        this.client.socket.on('data', data =>
        {
            chuncks.push(data)
        })
    })

    this.client.socket.on('end', () =>
    {
        let html = Buffer.concat(chuncks)
        console.log('--- HTML ---')
        console.log(html)
        let decoded = require('zlib').gunzipSync(html)

    })

    this.client.write( this.request ) // Above request
}
```

And, what i don't understand, is why things goes wrong, Am i make this properly ?

Thanks !

Comment: The content encoding is `gzip`.  Is that what is confusing you? Is there a reason you're trying to write your own http server when one is built right into node.js?

Comment: Oh, sorry it's that i made many tests but, in my code, i do `let html = require('zlib').gunzipSync(this.buffer)` and then node.js throw me ` incorrect header check`  

But i have simplified my anwser's code